# Set cursor position of htmleditor Extjs 6

Tags: extjs, cursor, cursor-position, html-editor, extjs6-classic

I'm using the htmleditor in my app, There I want to change the color of my text after 20 charachters.

So the first 20 characters will look black and after that, all will be orange

For this I'm using this code:

```
{
    xtype: 'htmleditor',
    value: record.data.description,
    height: 100,
    width: 900,
    name: 'instructionDescription',
    enableColors: false,
    enableFontSize: false,
    allowBlank: false,
    enableSourceEdit: false,
    enableLinks: false,
    enableFont: false,
    enableAlignments: false,
    enableLists: false,
    colspan: 2,
    style: {
        'margin-left': '10px'
    },
    listeners: {
        change: function(Object, newValue, oldValue) {
            if (typeof(newValue) != 'string')
                return;

            var newVal = Ext.util.Format.stripTags(newValue);
            var oldVal = Ext.util.Format.stripTags(oldValue);
            var index = newValue.indexOf('<font color="#ffa500">');
            var velue = null;
            if (newVal == oldVal)
                return;

            if (index > -1) {
                value = newValue.substr(0,index) + '<font color="#ffa500">' + newValue.substr(index + 22);
                this.setValue(value);
            }
            else {
                if (newVal.length > 20) {
                    newValue = newValue.replace('&nbsp;', " ");
                    newVal = Ext.util.Format.stripTags(newValue);
                    if (newVal.length < 21) {
                        return;
                    }
                    index = newValue.indexOf(Ext.util.Format.stripTags(newValue).substr(15,5));
                    index += 5;
                    value = newValue.substr(0,index) + '<font color="#ffa500">' +newValue.substr(index);
                    value = value.replace('&nbsp;', " ");
                    this.setValue(value);
                }
            }
        },
        afterrender: function() {
            var value = record.data.description;
            if (Ext.util.Format.stripTags(value).length > 20) {
                var index = value.indexOf(Ext.util.Format.stripTags(value).substr(20));
                value = value.substr(0,index) + '<font color="#ffa500">' + value.substr(index);
                value = value.replace('&nbsp;', " ");
            }
            this.setValue(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Now the issues is my cursor go back to first position when that color style applies on string after 20 characters.

Is there any way to stop the cursor going back the the first position or any way to manually set the position of cursor.

Comment: Hey Rohan - welcome to SO, please have a read here for posting good SO questions:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: A few pointers unrelated to your question for better coding: you should always use curly brackets in your `if`/`else` statements. It is more readable and can prevent future problems. If there is nothing inside your `else` statement but another `if`/`else` statement, you should use `else if`. You shouldn't set a variable value inside a single scope more than once, specifically I mean your setting of `index` and `value` variables on two consecutive lines. Use strict comparison wherever possible (preferably always).

Comment: This will give you some work to be accomplished specially because htmleditors use and I frame with an editable body so everything you do there is being added as a tag to the body of the page. The best idea is to add a method that will create selection ranges and every time you type get the current cursor position, set the colors using ranges and the `document.execCommand()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand - ant then reposition the cursor using selection and focus.